# ReCaptcha API can not be loaded by hand

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I'm having a bug on my website that I can't fix. I'm using Google's ReCaptcha API, and everything runs fine (the captcha appears and I'm able to check the results of the challenge). However I keep getting this error, which prevents another code to run : "**reCaptcha API can not be loaded by hand, delete reCaptcha API snippet"**

I'm sorry in advance if I'm not able to give enough information, that's because I really don't know what's going on, so feel free to ask if you have questions.

Here's what my code looks like :

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitted (r) {
        if(r.length == 0)
            alert("Please solve the captcha");
    }

    function onloadCallback() {
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
            'sitekey' : MY_KEY,
            'callback' : submitted
        });
    };

$('#some_button a').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: my_url + "recaptcha.php",
        data: {
            response: grecaptcha.getResponse(),
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data){
            if(typeof data.errors === 'undefined')
                $('form').submit();
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Any idea what I'm missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### copy of https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator/issues/712 by victorjonsson:

You can not have the google recaptcha initialisation present in the markup when loading the security module. You must configure recaptcha via jquery-form-validator.

http://www.formvalidator.net/index.html#security-validators_recaptcha